# Workflows comparing a date for today

Tags: 2010, workflow

I am working on a sharepoint workflow and have a date column where I want it so its greater or equal to todays date to do something. Would I just put Today as a string? or do I have to do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use Today as date type and make comparison. It works.